# Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: exec: "./run.sh": stat ./run.sh: no such file or directory

Tags: docker

When I run my docker container:

```
docker run my_image
```

Everything is fine and works as expected.
Then I want to mount volume:

```
docker run -v /data:/c_data my_image
```

But I have an error:

```
Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: exec: "./run.sh": stat ./run.sh: no such file or directory
```

I guess that error is raised due to the fact that `docker` looks for `run.sh` in `/data` directory, not in `c_data` where it is located.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Please post your dockerfile.

Comment: I suspect you are mixing up the order in `-v /data:/c_data` -- as it stands, your host directory `/data` will appear as `/c_data` within the container; is that what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The default `WORKDIR` is `/` so Docker is looking for `run.sh` in that directory. Since it is not there Docker is throwing an error. Try copying the `run.sh` to `/` , setting the `WORKDIR` to the location of the `run.sh` or giving the absolute path to the file to resolve this issue.